# Was failure of choice proved consistent with Zermelo or MacLane or TST before forcing?

Tags: ho.history-overview

It was forcing that first proved that there are models of $\sf ZF$ which in which $\sf AC$ fails.

Was that result known for $\sf Zermelo$ or $\text{MacLane Set Theory}$ or for [$\sf TST$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Foundations#The_Type_Theory_TST) before forcing? I mean that those have models in which $\sf AC$ fails.

I know that the result was proved before forcing for the case of $\sf ZFA$. But, for the above theories, they have full Extensionality.

Comment: According to your Wikipedia link, TST (I thought it was called STT) has Extensionality only for positive types, objects of type $0$ are "individuals". Is that what you meant by "full Extensionality"? Aren't "individuals" the same as "urelements"? (I wouldn't know, not being a logician or a set-theoretician.)

Comment: @bof, In the setting of TST, Ur-elements are taken to be individuals that are distinct from each other and yet have the same members, the base-level individuals (i.e. type $0$ individuals) are usually excluded from this, for although they are distinct, yet you cannot speak of their membership. In other theories, like Kripke-Platek with Ur-elements, you have a similar situation to the base individuals of TST, and they are labeled as Ur-elements there. But, this is not usually the setting for TST.

Comment: @bof.. continuation , and actually TSTU (which is TST with Ur-elements) is the theory that have Ur-elements at successor types, and not just that it has them at every successor type. So, in the setting of TST, it is considered as fully extensional in that sense, although in spirit it is not, it does have Ur-elements (the type $0$ individuals), but it fails seeing them as such.

Comment: Possibly related: Mathias has a series of papers on weak set theories. One of them (*Set forcing over models of Zermelo or Mac Lane*) mentions that forcing doesn't work quite well over those theories due to lack of replacement/collection. Any independence result obtained without forcing would be very interesting